# chrome extension - alternative to externally_connectable?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It seems like the externally_connectable feature that allows a website to communicate with an extension is still in the dev channel and not yet stable. Are there any other ways to allow a specific website to communicate with my extension, while I wait for this feature to become stable? How have chrome extension developers traditionally done it?

Comment: Custom messages / postMessage - see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

Comment: Thanks Rob. I explored that and it worked for me. Posting a longer answer below so it might help others.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's up now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Rob W for pointing me in the direction of HTML5 messaging. For the benefit of other chrome extension developers, I'm writing about the general problem I was trying to solve and the solution that worked in the end.

I am making a chrome extension that can control music playback on a tab via a popup player. When a user clicks on play/pause/etc on the popup player, the extension should be able to convey that message to the webpage and get back a response stating whether the action was accomplished.

My first approach was to inject a content script into the music player page. The problem is, though, that content scripts operate in a "sandbox" and cannot access native javascript on the page. Therefore, the content script was pretty useless (on its own), because while it could receive commands from the extension, it could not effect any change on the webpage itself.

One thing that worked in my favor was that the website where the music was playing belongs to me, so I could put whatever javascript I wanted there and have it be served from the server. That's exactly what I used to my advantage: I created another javascript file that would reside on the website and communicate with the content script mentioned above, via the window object of the page (i.e. **HTML5 messaging**). This only works because the content script and the javascript file both exist in the same webpage and can share the window object of the page. Thanks Rob W for pointing me to this capability. Here is an example of how the javascript file on the page can initiate a connection with the content script via the window object:

content_script.js (injected by extension into xyz.com):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data.secret_key &&
      (event.data.secret_key === "my_secret_key") && 
       event.data.source === "page"){
        if(event.data.type){
            switch(event.data.type) {
                case 'init':
                    console.log("received connection request from page");
                    window.postMessage({source: "content_script", type: 'init', 
                                        secret_key: "my_secret_key"}, "*");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

onpage.js (resides on server and served along with xyz.com):

```
window.postMessage({source: "page", type: 'init', 
                    secret_key: "my_secret_key"}, "*");

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data.secret_key && 
      (event.data.secret_key === "my_secret_key") && 
       event.data.source === "content_script"){
        if(event.data.type){
            switch(event.data.type) {
                case 'init':
                    console.log("connection established");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

I check the secret key just to make sure that the message originates from where I expect it to.

That's it! If anything is unclear, or if you have any questions, feel free to follow up!

Answer (score 0):

You could have an extension inject a content script alongside a web page, and use that to pass messages back and forth between the website and the background page of the extension.

It's tedious, though, and externally connectable is a lot nicer.

Comment: I've tried that before but content scripts cannot access native javascript code on the website (for obvious security reasons), so it didn't offer me the capability that I was looking for, which was precisely to be able to call some functions on the website. What I ended up doing does involve a content script being injected into the page, but also a script on the page itself. See my longer answer below.