# Chrome Extension -- externally_connectable and any way to set "matches" entries upon install

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have created a Chrome Extension that is a companion to web sites that we host for our customers.  These web sites are hosted under our domain name and interact with the extension using external messaging and relying on the sites being configured in the manifest similar to the following (abcdefg.com is a ficticious domain name):

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [ "http://*.abcdefg.com/*", "https://*.abcdefg.com/*"]
}
```

This works great in these cases.  However, we have a subset of customers that prefer to host the website themselves under their own domain.  The problem is that we do not want to update the extension manifest for the published extension to include all of these sites.

Is there any option of distributing a version of the extension (on Windows) where the "externally_connectable" site list can be set upon installation?

Comment: You'll have to use a content script to relay the messages on domains whitelisted by users in the extension options. [chrome extension - alternative to externally\_connectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18154599)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It isn't the ideal solution, but using the content script approach to messaging looks like it will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to kzahel for highlighting the obstacles I was facing and thanks to wOxxOm for providing a solution that will work.

Rather than trying to find a way to override the "externally_connectable" matches configuration upon installation, we found the easiest alternative was to avoid external messaging and use messaging via a content script instead.

The following is a copy of the solution posted above by wOxxOm:
[chrome extension - alternative to externally_connectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18154599)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this. You'll need to create a custom extension for every customer with their own domain name. Luckily, there is an API for updating the extension, so you would be able to at least update multiple extensions without too much difficulty. However, the 20 extension limit per account would be a little annoying. I think you can get more extension allowed per account by creating a publishing group and assigning the extensions there.

Comment: This really is unfortunate, but we really do have an atypical case.  Sure wish we could have been able to easily do this upon installation, but the 20 extension limit and the extra effort during deployment to make this happen just wasn't going to work out for the long term.  Fortunately, there is a workaround mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you are willing to have customers install this in developer mode. That would bypass the 20-extension limit.